# My computer start up with "program problem detected"

Tags: 14.04, kernel, startup, crash

When I start up the computer, enter the password, a window show up says:"system program problem detected." I can see the desktop image and the cursor and I can move it, but no respond including trying to type ctrl+alt+t to invoke the terminal.

So I need to press the power button and force the computer to shut down. Restart it again, the same message show up again but the computer is well functional. **I want to figure out how to fix the problem. I don't want to start computer twice every time.** Thanks a lot.

I've search the web, the "solution" is to delete the message under `/var/crash/` and to turn off the report by `/etc/default/apport`, which doesn't fix my problem at all, still need to start twice.

Here is the message abstracted from `/var/crash/`, it says some kernel problem and the system is not stable. I do not fully understand it.

```
ProblemType: KernelOops
Annotation: Your system might become unstable now and might need to be restarted.
Date: Fri Oct  9 21:25:22 2015
Failure: oops
OopsText:
 BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at fffffffffffffff8
 IP: [<ffffffff81207176>] eventpoll_release_file+0x46/0xa0
 PGD 1c11067 PUD 1c13067 PMD 0 
 Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP 
 Modules linked in: ctr ccm bnep rfcomm bluetooth binfmt_misc snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_core videodev arc4 snd_hda_intel intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_hda_codec intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_hwdep kvm snd_pcm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd snd_page_alloc thinkpad_acpi nvram snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi joydev serio_raw rtl8192ce snd_seq nouveau rtl_pci rtlwifi mxm_wmi rtl8192c_common ttm snd_seq_device snd_timer i915 rtsx_pci_ms drm_kms_helper mac80211 lpc_ich snd memstick cfg80211 mei_me drm mei i2c_algo_bit wmi shpchp soundcore mac_hid video parport_pc ppdev lp parport hid_generic usbhid hid rtsx_pci_sdmmc psmouse ahci libahci r8169 mii rtsx_pci
 CPU: 1 PID: 1441 Comm: pulseaudio Not tainted 3.13.0-66-generic #107-Ubuntu
 Hardware name: LENOVO 20178  /20178  , BIOS H2ET68WW(1.68) 05/17/2013
 task: ffff88008ed84800 ti: ffff88008ee08000 task.ti: ffff88008ee08000
 RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff81207176>]  [<ffffffff81207176>] eventpoll_release_file+0x46/0xa0
 RSP: 0018:ffff88008ee09e78  EFLAGS: 00010282
 RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffffffffffffb7 RCX: 000000000000000f
 RDX: 0000000001000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffffffff81c72e80
 RBP: ffff88008ee09ea0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000040000
 R10: ffff88008efceaa1 R11: 0000000000000206 R12: ffffffffffffffa8
 R13: ffff88008efceaa1 R14: ffff880092393cc0 R15: ffff88008ee5a9b0
 FS:  00007f5bfc697740(0000) GS:ffff88013f240000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
 CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
 CR2: fffffffffffffff8 CR3: 000000008ee04000 CR4: 00000000001407e0
 Stack:
  ffff88008ee5a900 0000000000000010 ffff88008efceaa1 ffff880092393cc0
  ffff88008ee05300 ffff88008ee09ee8 ffffffff811c00aa 0000000000000000
  ffff88008ed84800 0000000000000000 ffffffff81ebb680 ffff88008ed84e20
 Call Trace:
  [<ffffffff811c00aa>] __fput+0x24a/0x260
  [<ffffffff811c010e>] ____fput+0xe/0x10
  [<ffffffff81088557>] task_work_run+0xa7/0xe0
  [<ffffffff81013ed7>] do_notify_resume+0x97/0xb0
  [<ffffffff81734f5a>] int_signal+0x12/0x17
 Code: 00 41 56 41 55 41 54 53 e8 68 37 52 00 49 8b 07 48 8b 08 49 39 c7 4c 8d 60 a8 48 8d 59 a8 75 0b eb 3e 0f 1f 00 49 89 dc 48 89 d3 <4d> 8b 74 24 50 4d 8d 6e 08 4c 89 ef e8 39 37 52 00 4c 89 e6 4c 
 RIP  [<ffffffff81207176>] eventpoll_release_file+0x46/0xa0
  RSP <ffff88008ee09e78>
 CR2: fffffffffffffff8
 ---[ end trace 5b41d5dd63eaa023 ]---
Package: linux-image-3.13.0-66-generic 3.13.0-66.107
SourcePackage: linux
Tags: kernel-oops
Uname: Linux 3.13.0-66-generic x86_64
```

If you need more information, ask me and I'll post it.

Comment: You installed an unsupported kernel with a bug in it.

Comment: or you can run `ubuntu-bug` and send this to support.

Comment: @AizuddinZali it is a well known bug and it has been fixed already.

Comment: @Pilot6 How can I fix it?

Comment: Read the link I gave.

Comment: You need to boot from a previous kernel and remove 3.13.0-66

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks, I've got your idea. I'm doing it!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about an unsupported kernel.